# Represent semi-planes with Pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'm very new to TeX and need to make some occasional graphics, especially function plots. I saw somewhere on here that the easiest package to use for this would be `pgfplots`, so I've been using that and it's been working like a charm.

However, I need to represent semiplanes now, and despite my frantic Googling I can't seem to find an easy way to do it with the package. Of course I can use another package, but I didn't want to deviate too much from this onto "uncharted ground" that is too complex.

What I'd really like is a way to represent semiplanes from their equations - for example, I'd put in something like `y < -2x + 1` and it'd show the semiplane like [on Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xtjebnqkre). It'd be nice to have it fade off, but it's not necessary if that'd be too complex.

I apologize if this seems like I'm asking you to do all the work, but I seriously have no idea where to start, and I'm sure there's an easy way to do this I'm too new to know. Alternatively, my next possible guess would be to plot something out of the bounds of the picture and then use `fill between` between that and the semiplane's bound.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! I would be surprised if this wasn't done somehow and somewhere, but here is a version in which you only need to specify something like

```
ycrit(\x)=-2*\x+1;
```

shade the half plane below that line.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,minor tick num=4,grid=both,
      xmin=-5,xmax=5,ymin=-5,ymax=5,
      set layers,declare function={ycrit(\x)=-2*\x+1;}]
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{axis background}
     \path[fill=red!20]
        ({(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}-ycrit(0))/(ycrit(1)-ycrit(0))},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax})
        --
        ({(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}-ycrit(0))/(ycrit(1)-ycrit(0))},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})
        edge[dashed,red]
        ({(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}-ycrit(0))/(ycrit(1)-ycrit(0))},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax})
        -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})
        |- cycle;
        ;
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works great, thanks! How would I go about a semiplane with a vertical line as a bound though, like `x > 3`? I'm assuming this won't work because that's not a function